# "Content" blade/menu item missing from deployed admin site

Tags: virtocommerce

The "Content" link is missing from the "Browse" menu on my deployed admin site ( virtotest.cloudapp.net/admin ). It works fine when debugging the solution in visual studio.

The server-side content module loads fine, and content.js script loads ok, but the .factory .config and .run functions never get executed.

Just wanted to check if anybody has come across this one before I get too deep into investigating it.

Comment: I look at your admin site, and it wondering, "content" module run method never executed. It very strange i'll continue to examine and give you concrete suggestion if i'll find some thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you module `rollingLineOfCredit.js` you have copy paste bug.
You use **moduleName** variable instead of **moduleTemplateName**.

```
// Call this to register our module to main application
var moduleTemplateName = "platformWebApp.rollingLineOfCredit";

if (AppDependencies != undefined) {
    AppDependencies.push(moduleName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eugeney. I'm new to angular, so I'd rather not think about how long it would have taken me to find this :)